# Testing NgRx effects has stopped working after upgrade to Angular 15

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm using NgRx effects in an an Angular application. After upgrading to Angular 15, the tests stopped working with the following error message:

```bash
Error: NG0202: This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 0 of the parameter list is invalid.
This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator.

Please check that 1) the type for the parameter at index 0 is correct and 2) the correct Angular decorators are defined for this class and its ancestors.
```

But the class under test is annotated and the constructor parameters are correctly typed.

The class under test:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ProductEffects {
  constructor(private store$: Store<ProductState>, private actions$: Actions<ProductAction>, private productService: ProductService) {}

  requestActiveProducts = createEffect(() =>
// ... effects
}
```

The test:

```js
describe('ProductEffects', () => {
  let storeSpy: Mocked<Store<ProductState>>;
  let productServiceSpy: Mocked<ProductService>;

  let actions$: Observable<ProductAction>;
  let effects: ProductEffects;

  beforeEach(() => {
    storeSpy = createSpyObj('Store', ['select']);
    productServiceSpy = createSpyObj('ProductService', [... ]);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: Store, useValue: storeSpy },
        { provide: ProductService, useValue: productServiceSpy },
        ProductEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions$),
      ],
      imports: [StoreModule.forRoot({})],
      teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false },
    });
    effects = TestBed.inject(ProductEffects); // error occurs here
  });
```

From package.json:

```json
    "@angular/core": "15.0.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "15.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I forgot to update `@angular/cli` in `devDependencies`.

From the [NgRx migration guide for v15](https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v15):

> Version 15 has the minimum version requirements:
>
> Angular version 15.x, Angular CLI version 15.x, TypeScript version 4.8.x
> RxJS version ^6.5.3 || ^7.5.0

So after updating the dependencies as follows, it worked:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "15.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "15.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.0.2",
    ...
  }
```